# Windows 8.1 refuses to recognize my extra HDDs

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, partitioning, sata

Alright, so I've been trying to install a few extra hard drives since my storage has been getting quite full recently. However, Windows 8.1 will not let me set the disks up for proper use, or do anything with them, really.

I have a 2TB WD Caviar Green plugged into SATA3_1 that works perfectly fine, and is what I boot off of. The first HDD that is not functioning right is a 320GB Fujitsu something-or-other plugged into SATA3_2, which is totally unrecognized by Windows. The second HDD that isn't working is a 500GB Seagate something-or-other plugged into SATA3_6 (the only plug my short SATA cable could reach) and I can view it in Disk Management, but it's inaccessible and has some strange properties when trying to, y'know, manage it.

First it shows up and has one volume that appears unformatted with no drive letter assigned and with no attributes:

[image: (image)]

It lets me delete the volume, and all that remains is that unallocated space. However, when I try to create a new simple volume (drive letter X, NTFS w/ default allocation size, not quick format), Disk Management hangs for a while before yelling at me that apparently it can't do anything since something has changed, and that I should refresh the window or reboot:

[image: (image)]

Neither of those things change this. The drive then looks exactly as I started. I cannot change the drive letter or check the drive's properties, it giving the same error. If I try to format the disk, it gives me a different but even less helpful error, saying there was some unexpected error and to do the same things. Exactly the same problems happen if I use DiskPart in Windows PowerShell.

However, both disks function perfectly in Ubuntu! With gparted, I can format them (and I did, and the same stuff happens) and access them and partition them and all, so I know both drives function perfectly (and they do function perfectly in my laptop).

Can anyone shed some light on what the hell's going on? I've had this problem for days, and after some googling, I'm still stuck. Please note I'm not going to refresh my computer because I'm not prepared to lose my 2TB of data.

Edit 1: The exact same problems are occurring when I instead plug the HDDs into a USB3.0 external HDD enclosure. However, I feel no drive activity when holding the extra HDDs in the external enclosure, so Windows might have a problem with these drives in particular, or perhaps my enclosure is broken. I can't tell if there is any activity when they are plugged in internally, since my primary HDD is so close to them that it's hard to feel them vibrating or not.

Comment: what's the filesystem on _2, _6?

Comment: _2 is NTFS (previously HFS+, don't know if that's important) and _6 is NTFS as well (and has always been). In addition, both of these as well as _1 are MBR.